# Get input text at specific row of html table when check box at that row is checked

Tags: php, html

I have a html table with check box on every row and when I click the checkboxes at a specific row, i am supposed to echo the input text using php. However, I can only get the input text for the first row. All the other rows give me a blank data. I dont understand whats wrong with my code

```
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
         foreach($_POST['test'] as $key=>$value)
               { 
                  echo $_POST['tCode'][$key];
                 }
            }

        ?>
          <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


                <div style="width:48%; margin-left:440px">
    <table border="0px" align="center" class = "table" style="margin-right:530px;">
 <form name="MainForm" method="post" action=""  >
        <tr>
            <th style = "float:right">Tracking code:</th>
            <th>
               <td> <input type="textbox" name="tCode[]" id="1" ></td>
       <td> <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="name" value ="1" /> 
          </td>
            </th>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <th style = "float:right" >Order Code: </th>
            <th>
                 <td> <input type="textbox" name="tCode[]" id="2" ></td>
          <td> <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="name" value ="2" /> 
           </td>
            </th>
            <th>
              </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <th style = "float:right" >product Code: </th>
               <th>
                      <td> <input type="textbox" name="tCode[]" id="3" > 
         </td>
             <td> <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="name1" value ="3"/></td>
            </th>
            <th>
                      </tr>
                <td></td>
             <td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" name = "submit" style="margin-left:50px" /></td>
```

When i tick the first checkbox, and type hello world in the first texbox, click submit, it is able to echo out "hello world", whereas for the other checkboxes, the inputted text is blank despite the textbox having value in it.

Comment: One thing you should consider is adjusting the names of the inputs - you can pass the ID via the name: `name="tCode[1]` and `name=tCode[2]`, etc.

Comment: I have tried.. but it produces a similar outcome

Comment: Try and debug: what does `echo <pre>;` `print_r($_POST)` `echo </pre>` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there's lots of things going on here that are worth addressing.  Keep in mind this comes from the spirit of wanting to help you become a better coder.  Not all of it applies to PHP, but all of the feedback will help you be a better coder in general.

1. Do NOT use inline styles.  They are frowned upon, they make the code messy / hard to diagnose, and they make maintenance very difficult.
2. DO use a code editor that will hilight issues for you (I'm a huge fan of PHPStorm).  The code had all kinds of mismatched html tags that I have cleaned up below.
3. Do NOT use `id`s unnecessarily.  On html inputs, there are only two purposes for using `id`s: (a) So you can address them with CSS styles, or (b) So you can access them easily with some javascript code.  You were doing neither, so I stripped out all the ID's.
4. DO format your code with proper spacing and indenting.  Formatting makes it far easier to read and troubleshoot.
5. DO put the PHP "key" inside the name of the inputs.  This is one of the reasons you were having difficulties - the indexes did not match.
6. DO use defensive coding (checking if something `isset`, is `! empty`, or `array_key_exists`) before accessing an array element.  Note I used `array_key_exists` below - that's because other methods can still return FALSE, even if it was set (but there was no value).

**The reason it didn't work** is because checkboxes are only present in the `$_POST` superglobal *if they are checked*.  Therefore, the indexes *did not match* like you expected them to.  For example, checking ONLY the second box resulted in a `$key` of 1, NOT 2 as you would expect.

I've updated the inputs, as well as the PHP, to work.

The below code has been updated, and tested, and proven to work:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
    // this is for debugging / testing.  Comment / remove as necessary
    var_dump( $_POST );

    // load ALL of the text inputs for convenient access in the loop
    $codes = $_POST['tCode'];    

    // test first to be sure ANY checkboxes were checked, to prevent notices
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'test' ] ) ) {
        // loop over all posted checkboxes
         foreach( $_POST[ 'test' ] as $key => $on ) { 
             // isset or ! empty can return FALSE if present, but empty value
             if ( array_key_exists( $key, $codes ) ) {
                 echo '<br>The input for row ' . $key . ' is: ' . $codes[ $key ];   
             }
         }
     }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="MainForm" method="post" action="" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Tracking code:
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="textbox" name="tCode[1]" >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="test[1]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style = "float:right" >
                        Order Code: 
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="textbox" name="tCode[2]" >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="test[2]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        product Code: 
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="textbox" name="tCode[3]" >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="test[3]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh my it works! Thanks a ton... Honestly, i rarely see people who are as patient and gives many valuable advice like you. I will take note of the advices you gave... Thanks once again

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck!